# Two values in one switch case

Tags: php, html, mysql, switch-statement, case

I'm a newbie so please bear with me.
I want a radio button that when the user picks one, two values will be sent to the database(records table). One is the kind of service that was chosen by the user, and the other one is the corresponding price of it. BUT the 'services' and 'prices' are from another table which means that the value depends on the content of the 'ms_pricelist' database. Here are my codes:

(this is my input form. Let's try to focus on the `<input type="radio">` buttons)

```
                    <form method="post" action="">
                    <table style="width: 10%;">

     <p style="font-size: 30px; font-family: Verdana;"> &nbsp Service Contract </p>
      <hr style="margin-top: -20px; width: 95%;">

    <p style="margin-left: 50px;">Name of Deceased:  <input type="text" name="service_deceased" value="<?php echo $query2['service_deceased']; ?>" />
    <br><br>

    <p style="margin-left: 50px;">Type of Service:  
    <input type="radio" name="service_type">Sunny Star</button>
    <input type="radio" name="service_type">Lemon Tropic</button>
    <input type="radio" name="service_type">White Fairy</button><br> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="service_type">Chinese Holy</button>
    <input type="radio" name="service_type">Red Ginger</button>
    <input type="radio" name="service_type">Blue Days</button></p>
     &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

    <p style="margin-left: 50px;">Amount:   <input type="text" name="service_amount" value="<?php echo $query2['service_amount']; ?>" />
      </p>

    <p style="margin-left: 410px;">  NET AMOUNT:  <input type="text" name="net_amount" value="<?php echo $query2['net_amount']; ?>" />
    <br></p>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" style="margin-left: 1000px; height: 50px; width: 150px;" />
    </form>
```

This is my 'ms_pricelist' database

```
[ms_priceID |    ms_name   | ms_price]
--------------------------------------
[    1      |  Sunny Star  |    28000]
[    2      | Lemon Tropic |    48000]
[    3      |  White Fairy |    58000]
[    4      | Chinese Holy |    98000]
[    5      |  Red Ginger  |   168000]
[    6      |   Blue Days  |   250000]
```

'service_type' is where the ms_name should be stored in the records table and 'service_amount' for the ms_price.

Is it possible? I've been searching for answers for almost a month but still can't find one. Any suggestions on how to accomplish it? I'm using PHP and MYSQL. Thank you so much in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here's the php code for the form.

```
<?php
include('connect-db.php');
    if(isset($_GET['CustomerNumber']))
    {
        $CustomerNumber=$_GET['CustomerNumber'];
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {

            $crc_no = $_POST['crc_no'];
            $date_of_service = $_POST['date_of_service'];
            $date_of_interment = $_POST['date_of_interment'];
            $authorized_family = $_POST['authorized_family'];
            $rel_to_deceased = $_POST['rel_to_deceased'];
            $rel_address = $_POST['rel_address'];
            $service_phone_no = $_POST['service_phone_no'];
            $service_deceased = $_POST['service_deceased'];
            $service_type = $_POST['service_type'];
            $service_amount = $_POST['service_amount'];
            $less_service = $_POST['less_service'];
            $net_amount = $_POST['net_amount'];

            $query3=mysql_query("UPDATE records SET crc_no='$crc_no', date_of_service='$date_of_service', date_of_interment='$date_of_interment', authorized_family='$authorized_family', rel_to_deceased='$rel_to_deceased', rel_address='$rel_address', service_phone_no='$service_phone_no', service_deceased='$service_deceased', rel_address='$rel_address', service_phone_no='$service_phone_no', service_deceased='$service_deceased', service_type='$service_type', service_amount='$service_amount', less_service='$less_service', net_amount='$net_amount' WHERE CustomerNumber='$CustomerNumber'");
            if($query3)
            {
            header('location: fill.php');
            }
            }
            $query1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM records where CustomerNumber='$CustomerNumber'");
            $query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
            ?>
```

This PHP works fine af. But the radio button (or other solutions you may suggest) I want is the only thing that's not working.

Comment: This is **NOT** how you should `input type="radio"`. :)

Comment: I Did not understand your question, be more specif please.

Comment: If you need more than one table, please show us all necessary tables. Also, if you are using php, where is your code for that? Without seeing what you have tried it will be difficult to help answer your questions.

Comment: It is true that the question is presented quite chaotically. Please improve the structure of what you are asking. For example - you say `the 'services' and 'prices' are from another table`, yet what you show us is only one table where both things are present in **a single** table...

Comment: @Smuuf I need a hand bro. Can you give me some sample codes for this? I'm losing it. :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Your description is vague and your code is very limited.
From what I understand what you need to do is that, you need to check which of the radio button is checked and then you query the ms_pricelist database for the row where ms_name = your checked radio button. Then use the ms_price value for that row.